# setState is not working iqual on iOS than Android

Tags: ios, flutter, setstate

I am doing some charge information with shared preference but in iOS is not working while in Android is working as expected

```
@override
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    readData();
}
```

I have 2 textfields for fill it up when readData() have data

```
final email = TextFormField(
      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
      autofocus: false,
      initialValue: _email,
      validator: (input) {
        if(input.isEmpty) {
          return 'Introduce un Email';
        }
      },
      onSaved: (input) => _email = input,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
          hintText: 'Email',
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 10.0, 20.0, 10.0),
          border:
          OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32.0))),
);

final password = TextFormField(
      autofocus: false,
      obscureText: true,
      initialValue: _password,
      validator: (input) {
        if(input.isEmpty) {
          return 'Introduce la contraseña';
        }
      },
      onSaved: (input) => _password = input,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
          hintText: 'Contraseña',
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 10.0, 20.0, 10.0),
          border:
          OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32.0))),
);
```

```
readData() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    setState(() {
      _email = prefs.getString('email');
      _password = prefs.getString('password');
    });
}
```

In android works well but not in iOS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the right way to update the value of the textfields is to use a `TextEditingController`.
Your code would look like this:

**In your state**

```
final TextEditingController emailCtrl = TextEditingController();
final TextEditingController passwordCtrl = TextEditingController();

readData() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    emailCtrl.text = prefs.getString('email');
    password.text = prefs.getString('password');
}
```

**Your TextFields**

```
final email = TextFormField(
     // ... your other arguments
    controller: emailCtrl
);
final password = TextFormField(
     // ... your other arguments
    controller: passwordCtrl
);
```